# How to retrieve the text node for each item in a HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

having a hard time to get this done. I have the following:

```
<p class='abc'>text 1</p>
<p class='abc'>text 2</p>
```

Then I tried something like:

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

for(var i=0;i < texts.length; i++){
   console.log(texts[i].text);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Also tried with Jquery but to no avail.

Comment: `texts[i].innerText` or `texts[i].innerHTML` ?

Comment: when is the javascript called relative to the html?

Comment: `textContent` or `innerText` depending on browser

Comment: could you guys stop downvoting questions? jeez... it was a legit doubt.

Comment: .innerHTML works. Tnx!

Answer (score 6):

The property you're looking for is [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

for(var i=0;i < texts.length; i++){
   console.log(texts[i].textContent);
}
```

However, older IE versions only support a [non-standard innerText attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx), so you might need to fall back to that:

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

for(var i=0;i < texts.length; i++){
   console.log(texts[i].textContent || texts[i].innerText);
}
```

If you *are* using jQuery, it's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it.

Instead of:

```
console.log(texts[i].text);
```

You want:

```
console.log(texts[i].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.textContent`.

```js
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for(var i=0;i < texts.length; i++){
   alert(texts[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<p class='abc'>text 1</p>
<p class='abc'>text 2</p>
```